# 中 / 英 key does not work consistently on Ventura 13.2

Tags: keyboard, input-source

I use the 中 / 英 key to toggle input sources. Recently, the key does not toggle input sources unless I am using the Finder or a handful of other apps. For example, the key does not work in Google Chrome or Terminal. In Chrome and Terminal, pressing the key turns on a light in the key and makes all letters produced by pressing other keys capitalised until the key is pressed again.

There is a setting that says "Use the 中 / 英 key to switch to and from ABC" and I have
this set to true:

[image: 中 / 英 key setting]

This setting had worked flawlessly for years and seems to have stopped working consistently since I updated to Ventura 13.2, though something else may be causing the issue.

I am using a magic keyboard from Apple.

How do I make the key work consistently in all applications as it did before?

Comment: Do the other ways to change keyboards -- Control Space and Fn/Globe -- work more reliably?

Comment: @TomGewecke Yes, Control Space and Fn (when I change the setting in Settings) both consistently bring up a menu to choose an input source. That is a bit different from how 中 / 英 key works (there is no menu it just changes the input source) but I may use Fn if I can't get my usual key to work again.

Comment: I think I have seen other reports of the caps lock key being unreiiable.  You can report this to apple via    http://www.apple.com/feedback